# Possible to check NEST system compatibility by looking at current thermostat model?

Tags: furnace, thermostat, nest

I'd like to replace my [Honeywell CT87A thermostat](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-0274.pdf) with a Nest thermostat. I see that Nest has a page to check [system compatibility](https://store.nest.com/product/thermostat/#works/?mode=buy). Is it possible to identify if my system is compatible without taking it off of the wall, perhaps by the fact that I have a CT87A? It's bitter cold out and I don't want to turn off the fuse for the furnace.

Answer (score 1):

According to the installation instructions in your link, the Honeywell CT87A requires only two or three wires (R,W,[Y]) to operate.   The Nest compatibility checker shows that a system using those wires is compatible.   You should be good to go.